# Android: Open activity and animation when imagebutton clicked

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, android-activity

My MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,     R.anim.animation);
        b.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});
```

What this does is that when a ImageButton is clicked there is an animation, but i also want it to open a new activity when clicked, aswell as the animation, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Intent for the Activity you wish to start, then call `startActivity(intent);`